# Responsive carousel not working in Chrome smaller viewports, but works in FF

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, carousel, viewport, responsive

Please help I am looking for a fix. I have this website:
http://www.ktlpro.com/

This works perfectly from what I know in all browsers except CHROME @ certain viewports. I cannot figure out why this slider does not work properly.

I believe the viewports in Chrome that are having problems are 680, 768, and maybe 480. Please help!

How it looks in chrome:
[Chrome below 768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaBKd.png)

Comment: can you provide some screenshots of the problem and some screenshots of how it should look?

Comment: also you have a 404 error on a css stylesheet, which could be a reason why it's not working properly

Comment: i am sorry i need 10 rep for 2 photos :(

Comment: how do i find these errors you locate so easily, is there a website?

Comment: look at the picture attached on how it looks in chrome, the text should be more centered not overlapping. check another browser such as FF to see how or even desktop view.

Comment: right click and inspect element, then look in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following css between 480px and 767px:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
#main-slide .slider-content h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

change it to something like this and it will fix the problem:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
#main-slide .slider-content h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 65px; //You can increase this if you wish
}
```

[image: What it looks like with my CSS]